# OpenID Connect Configuration for Facebook

Tags: facebook, oauth-2.0, openid, openid-connect

Google had implemented [OpenID Discovery Spec](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-discovery-1_0.html) at https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration which allows developers and users to find the necessary URLs and keys for OpenID authentication.

I was wondering what the Facebook and possibly other (e.g. Microsoft Live) equivalents are so I can use Facebook and others in a standard fashion.

SalesForce also has a discovery URL https://login.salesforce.com/.well-known/openid-configuration

Comment: +1, it's hard to find this kind of information in [facebook's docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/v2.0).

Answer (score 14):

Here is OpenID Configuration For Facebook

https://www.facebook.com/.well-known/openid-configuration/

Comment: Upvoted because the original answers are out of date and Facebook has moved to OpenID standards.

Comment: Annoyingly, it doesn't adhere very strictly to the OpenID standard. For example, "response_mode" has no effect. And good luck using anything other than implicit flow.

Comment: There is no token endpoint here, so it seems like Facebook does not support OpenID Connect (at least not fully)

Comment: Looking at Facebook's docs that endpoint is for what they call "[limited login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/limited-login/token/)" where there seems to be some restrictions.

Answer (score 9):

Facebook's login mechanism/protocol is not based on OpenID Connect. Facebook uses a proprietary extension of OAuth 2.0 but it is not the standardized one that OpenID Connect specifies. Hence there's no point in expecting Facebook to publish OpenID Connect Discovery documents, unlike Google and Salesforce that do adhere to the standard.

Comment: is it the same case for twitter?

Comment: yes, and for GitHub. Not sure why they didn't implemented such easy but useful API

Answer (score 4):

Here is the OpenID Connect Discovery URL for Microsoft Azure AD:
https://login.windows.net/common/.well-known/openid-configuration

[More information here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn645541.aspx).

Comment: sort of weird that the issuer has a place holder "{tennantid}"

Comment: Hmm they require response_mode which is optional per the spec, interesting.  But got me to looking at what that value is.

Comment: the `response_mode` entry does not require anything on the client; it just says that the server supports all possible response modes

Comment: from the info `response_mode`

[Required] Indicates the encoding of the response. Supported values are fragment (URL fragment) and form_post (HTTP form POST).

Comment: sorry I misunderstood: I thought you were referring to the (also optional) entry in the Discovery document; seems indeed that this option must be provided by a client talking to the MS Provider

Comment: ya it seems it is there to get around an earlier but incorrect implementation.  No biggie, I wrote that into my RP code.